# What is the best free iOS wallet out there?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, wallet

I only ask this question because there's so many kinds of wallets out there and I understand the difference between wallets(hardware wallets, iOS and Desktop wallets). But what is the best wallet in your opinion? would you be recommending that wallet to someone that's located in Asia?

Comment: https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet?step=5&platform=ios

Answer (score 1):

I personally like [Blockstream Green](https://blockstream.com/green/) as in addition to being simple to use, it has many features about security and privacy

Answer (score 0):

I like [Blockstream Green](https://blockstream.com/green/) (they have multisig, with 2FA for larger payments, so extra security) and [BlueWallet](https://bluewallet.io/) (sometimes you might prefer singlesig for enhanced privacy + they have Lightning Network support in addition to on-chain Bitcoin).